# Backtrader 'File Not Found Error [ERRNO 2]'. Error with sample code from Backtrader Github page

Tags: python, file-not-found, backtrader

I ran across this error when trying to run the backtrader sample setup code found on github. After doing some research I found that the error probably stems from the Yahoo Finance API being out of date or no longer compatible with the backtrader package. I plan on using online data feeds for the backtesting I want to do, so does anyone know how I can fix the yahoo data feed issue? Some online sources suggested digging into the source code. I already tried those suggestions with no avail.

```
from datetime import datetime
import backtrader as bt


class SmaCross(bt.SignalStrategy):
    def __init__(self):
        sma1, sma2 = bt.ind.SMA(period=10), bt.ind.SMA(period=30)
        crossover = bt.ind.CrossOver(sma1, sma2)
        self.signal_add(bt.SIGNAL_LONG, crossover)

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.addstrategy(SmaCross)

data0 = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(dataname='AAPL', fromdate=datetime(2011, 1, 1),
                                  todate=datetime(2012, 12, 31))
cerebro.adddata(data0)

cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot()
```

Error Stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4abfaa589128> in <module>
     12 cerebro.adddata(data0)
     13 
---> 14 cerebro.run()
     15 cerebro.plot()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/cerebro.py in run(self, **kwargs)
   1125             # let's skip process "spawning"
   1126             for iterstrat in iterstrats:
-> 1127                 runstrat = self.runstrategies(iterstrat)
   1128                 self.runstrats.append(runstrat)
   1129                 if self._dooptimize:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/cerebro.py in runstrategies(self, iterstrat, predata)
   1208                 if self._exactbars < 1:  # datas can be full length
   1209                     data.extend(size=self.params.lookahead)
-> 1210                 data._start()
   1211                 if self._dopreload:
   1212                     data.preload()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feed.py in _start(self)
    201 
    202     def _start(self):
--> 203         self.start()
    204 
    205         if not self._started:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py in start(self)
    354 
    355         # Prepared a "path" file -  CSV Parser can take over
--> 356         super(YahooFinanceData, self).start()
    357 
    358 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py in start(self)
     92 
     93     def start(self):
---> 94         super(YahooFinanceCSVData, self).start()
     95 
     96         if not self.params.reverse:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feed.py in start(self)
    672             else:
    673                 # Let an exception propagate to let the caller know
--> 674                 self.f = io.open(self.p.dataname, 'r')
    675 
    676         if self.p.headers:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AAPL'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue that popped up this week. We have fixed it on Backtrader2 [here](https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67). Backtrader2 was created to keep urgent bug fixes up to date, since the original backtrader is a closed repo now.

If you wish, there is only one line change. You can adjust your local backtrader file to match this: https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67/files

In file `backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py`, you will find the following code at line 269:

```
crumb = None
sess = requests.Session()
```

Add the following code on the next line:

```
sess.headers['User-Agent'] = 'backtrader'
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the adjustment in the source code, but now I am getting an Import error.  ImportError: cannot import name 'warnings' from 'matplotlib.dates'. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting this error: `'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code, but there's probably a () where it shouldn't be. Check your import statements to see if you are adding () to a module where you need perhaps to import the class.